# How can I set number of parameters from jenkins running Python script?

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins

I am running Python job from Jenkins... now my question is as follow:

I am setting number of users as an external parameter, for example I am passing this command: 
python /home/py_version/single_run.py $number_of_users

i want to be able to set a way to choose what are the users (in this case users ids) from the jenkins or the script itself...

thanks!

Comment: Could you give some more information/samples on **to be able to set a way to choose what are the users**? Because you call the script and hand over the parameter, the variable inside the script that takes this parameter MUST be yours. In case that you handle users of different souces in your script, just use different variables to hold them.

Comment: OK, my script is being launched from jenkins with this command:
python /home/py_version/single_run.py $number_of_users

this variable will store number of users to be executed in the python script, now my goal is to define which users will be run in the script... where should I do it? from Python script or from Jenkins? and if so how can i do it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does jenkins also provide the information 'which users' too or just the 'number of users', so you would have to get the 'which users' by your own? I don't have a jenkins installation with administrativ access, so I cannot check this myself.

Comment: just the number of users as I far as I know, if I knew about another ability which can be configured which users via Jenkins I would have done it... as far as i know jenkins can't do that , so I just set number of users...